# What is the fault in this JS

Tags: jquery

```
!function ($) {
//=================================== scroll  ===================================//

    $body.scrollspy({
      target: '#navbar-main',
      offset: navHeight
    })

    $window.on('load', function () {
      $body.scrollspy('refresh')
    })

    $('#navbar-main [href=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    })


});
```

Comment: What error is reported?

Comment: Why !function ($) { ??

Comment: Are `$body` and `$window` jQuery objects for the respective tags?

Answer (score 4):

You are generating a function but never executing it.

```
!(function ($) {
//=================================== scroll  ===================================//

    $body.scrollspy({
      target: '#navbar-main',
      offset: navHeight
    })

    $window.on('load', function () {
      $body.scrollspy('refresh')
    })

    $('#navbar-main [href=#]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
    })


})(jQuery); // <-- Execute the function
```

Comment: That has fixed it. Cheers Joe!